# PostgreSQL tracking votes in a table?

Tags: postgresql, vote

I have a table with a simple up/down vote column which I originally created as a boolean. `true` is a vote up, `false` is a vote down. However, I'm not sure how to use aggregate functions to achieve this kind of query result. For example, 5 `true` rows and 2 `false` should equal a vote of +3.

I'm thinking that I need to change the column to a smallint with +1 and -1. Is this correct? Is there a better way to query something like this?

Comment: Personally I would prefer the 'smallint' solution. It will make your rows larger by 1 byte, but it will make the counting query faster. (The 1 byte is insignificant, the row header on disk alone is 24 bytes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to change the datatype, simply use a CASE to convert it to -1 and 1, then sum over the expression:

```
SELECT sum(case when vote_column then 1 else -1 end)
FROM your_table
```

To properly deal with NULL values, use the following

```
SELECT sum(case vote_column 
              when true then 1 
              when false then -1 
              else 0 
           end)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Or to include nulls: `sum(case vote_column when 1 then 1 when 0 then -1 else 0 end)`

Comment: @Ben: the nulls wouldn't be counted anyway as sum() skips null values

Comment: Is the case faster than just switching to a smallint? I have a lot of records and I would rather have the most optimal setup.

Comment: @Xeoncross: I don't think it will make a difference in speed. If the booleans are more convenient, stick with them. If you find integer to be more convenient go with that. But just for "summing up" there is no need to get rid of the boolean because of performance

Comment: @Xeoncross: If you're really worried about performance and you're computing totals a lot more than adding votes, then add a trigger to maintain a running total in a summary table. That'll add a slight hit during voting but drastically reduce computation when counting votes (which is possibly the most common access case).

Comment: @Xeoncross, in a_horse_with_no_name's `case` statement the nulls are converted to zero so won't be skipped, but counted as "no" votes. Skipped nulls also can produce a warning in some DBMSs, so it is best to handle them explicitly.

Comment: @Ben: hmm, not including the nulls is the way it should work according to he SQL standard. Could you tell me which DBMS isn't able to handle this properly?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, your `case` statement converts null values to -1, so there are no nulls in the `SUM`. You are correct about ANSI SQL, but skipped nulls can still produce a warning on some DBMSs including SQL Server depending on the ANSI `SET` options in force.